# Eclipse Orion: AutoSaving Keeping track of "local" history for edited files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-orion

We are investigating Orion and are trying to check if there is an option similar to eclipse where a user can see the local versions of a file he/she is currently editing. Is there an orion plugin for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of such a feature.

Even if it existed I would suggest to just init a git repository for each top-level Orion Content directory you work in. Choose Git repositories from the top-left menu.

See

[image]

pick More

[image]

and

[image]